# CSS class and descendant selectors practices

Tags: html, css-selectors, css

I would like to form a better understanding of when it is appropriate to use classes to target content as opposed to other available options, specifically, descendant selectors.

In many cases, instead of using classes, it is possible to use descendant selectors to target the same elements. If the same thing can be accomplished in both ways, what is the logic between deciding an option ?

Here are some example scenarios:

1.

a.

```
<div class="main">
     <div>
         <div> /* target */
             <div></div>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>

.main > div > div
```

b.

```
<div class="main">
     <div>
         <div class="content">
             <div></div>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>

.content
```

2.

a.

```
<div class="main">
     <div> /* target */
        <div></div>
     </div>
     <div> /* target */
        <div></div>
     </div>
</div>

.main > div:first-child
.main > div:last-child
```

b.

```
<div class="main">
     <div class="content1">
        <div></div>
     </div>
     <div class="content2">
        <div></div>
     </div>
</div>

.content1
.content2
```

3.

a.

```
<div class="main">
     <div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
     </div>
</div>

.main > div div
```

b.

```
<div class="main">
     <div class="content">
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
     </div>
</div>

.content div
```

What is the logic between deciding to use classes or descendant selectors ?

Comment: http://phrogz.net/css/HowToDevelopWithCSS.html#contextualselectors (see the note beginning with "…but don't rely on the markup too much")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Descendant selectors allow you to avoid embedding class information in your html.  This may be convenient when the wrapping block is a logical container.  For example, if you have constructed a table using `div` tags and you have hundreds, or thousands, of rows you could potentially cut down your document size, and increase readability, by specifying a descendant style instead of specifying `class='...'` repeatedly.

```
  <div class='mytable'>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <!-- A LOT MORE ROWS -->
  </div>
```

The advantage of specifying a class is that you aren't tied to a particular ordering.  It can be extremely frustrating having to alter your descendant tags each time you want to rearrange your view.  The other nice thing about specifying a class is that when working with CSS, it's far easier to search for a specific class name than have to decipher your descendant blocks.

To my knowledge, there aren't black & white guidelines as far as when each is appropriate.  Use your own discretion and consider the benefits/shortfalls of each as you design.

Comment: Not just descendant combinators, but any contextual selectors for that matter.

Answer (score 11):

To get the conversation started on the right foot checkout [What is a good CSS strategy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327382/what-is-a-good-css-strategy). Personally, I think the @gregnostic's strategies should be renamed to domains.

As I see it, every project with more than a a dozen webpages really needs to implement the various domains to certain degrees based on their scope.

The *domains* here being (ordered by specificity):

### Resetting

Attempts to achieve a baseline across browsers and environmental conditions. Made famous by [Eric Meyer](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/). A lot of people skip over this as a solved problem, but as someone who works on an on page Content Management system, believe me CSS resetting is important and can be a challenging problem to solve gracefully (esp. if the client is using the same theme library as you are).

These selectors should be as general as possible. Picking based on CSS classes doesn't normally make any sense, except, on occasion, when you *need* to reset inside a given shell.

### Layout

Potential page structures, often handled by a grid system of some sort. These should be a little more specific, but ought to rely on some sort of recursive pattern. Something like:

```
.row {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 30px;
} 

.row .col {
    width: 100%;
}

    .row.two .col {
        width: 50%;
    }
```

While this can be done with tag selection, I find it's almost never intuitive for the next person and you always wind up with a `grid` magically appearing in the wrong place. Using classes helps keep the **Junk drawer**<sup>TM</sup> smaller. For a full scale implementation see:

- 960 [Grid System](http://960.gs/)
- [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html)
- [Columnal](http://www.columnal.com/)
- Tons of others.

### Component/Functional

I tend to get very specific on these. One of my favorite patterns for this is [Stubornella's OOCSS](https://github.com/stubbornella). The basic concept is that in order to minimize duplicate code you bundle attributes inside of various CSS selectors and do your best to make them play nice together. A simple example of this is [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#buttons)'s buttons.

While you might be able to fudge in child selectors here, I'd strongly recommend against it as the first time someone wants to change:

```
<button type="button"></button>
```

to:

```
<button type="button">
    <span class="ugly-orange-bordered-purple-thing">
        My Button
    </span>       
</button>
```

The overly general:

```
button {
    border: 99em purple dotted;
}
```

Will totally conflict with:

```
.ugly-orange-bordered-purple-thing {
    border: 5em orange dashed;
    background-color: purple;
}
```

However, if you change `button` to `.btn` then you can simply moved that to the span or just left off.

### Typography

Handling the appropriate display of various fonts under given conditions. I always handle this element selector to the extent possible. I usually kick it off with something like:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

p, span, a, ... {
    font-family: serif; /* Or whatever. */
}

h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 1.8em;
}

... 

.row h2 {
    font-size: 1.6em;
}
```

Depending on the need of the client, I might even add in rules for spans inside of buttons.

### Theme

Much like the **Typography** domain, I tend toward tag selection a lot more in this area. Theme's are almost by definition throw away (since e.g., [Taco Bell](http://www.tacobell.com/) and [Mc Donald's](http://www.mcdonalds.com/us/en/home.html) don't want to have the same theme).

The Dojo toolkit has some nice examples of setting up themes as a separate layer (checkout [nihilo](http://svn.dojotoolkit.org/src/dijit/trunk/themes/nihilo/)). They tend toward classes here, but that's mainly for re-usability, which I already discussed.

### Junk drawer

The junk drawer of CSS, hopefully most of this is contained inside `<!--[if lt IE 9]>`, but every project has these and they should go in last. Keeping this empty is a priority, but it's not as important as getting the job done (something I keep trying to remind myself).

I make these really specific, since the last thing you want is to change the a rule like:

```
div div {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

on a nearly complete site. Wherever possible, I put these in a work place friendly "legacy" area.

### Closing notes

- When I do code reviews that have CSS in them, **Junk drawer** is the only place I want to see an id without a really good explanation.
- Like all other code, always attempt to follow the patterns of the surrounding code (unless it makes you eyes bleed).
- **Let me know if I missed something**

Comment: +1 good answer. I'd add, using a meta-language ([Sass](http://sass-lang.com/) is what I've settled on) has given me the ability to organize and not repeat myself _and_ I don't have to litter my markup with non-semantic class names.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the rest of your markup. Consider this modified version of your `1.a` example:

```
<div class="main">
     <div>
         <div> /* target */
             <div></div>
         </div>
     </div>
     <div>
         <div> /* target? */
             <div></div>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Selector `.main > div > div` would select both divs, which may or may not be what you want. So sometimes you have to be more specific, adding classes and ids to the markup, and tweaking the selectors accordingly.

There are multiple ways to select the same elements with CSS, not just one "correct" way. It's usually not recommended to be too specific, but too general selectors can cause problems too. You have to find a balance, and you only get there by practicing, there's no recipe.

Comment: Thanks for the response but you mostly answered in the same vague way as I read in many articles by saying "figure out what works better" without saying how to figure out which is better, what logic to follow. Just out of curiosity, for the exact markup in my examples, can you give me your choices and motivate them ?

Comment: @jsgroove I suspect you're not going to get a definitive answer here as there are many things to consider, performance (descendant selectors are slower than `id` or `class`), code maintainability (some advocate never using descendant selectors) etc. Throw in personal preferences and there's widely varying opinions.

Comment: For the exact markup in your examples, I'd use the same selectors you did. Sorry if I can't be more specific, it's just that there is no formula for that. You have to know your options and tools, and question yourself on the pros and cons of each option. You seem to be on the right path!

Comment: @bfavaretto Sorry if I wasn't to clear, I meant which option, a or b would you use in each of the 3 examples if the markup in the <div class="main"> would be only the one exemplified.

Comment: @jsgroove I can't believe I ignored that :) I usually prefer option b on all three cases. I try to use class names that clearly state the element's role, so it's easier to read my CSS and JS files. I tend to leave descendant selectors and pseudoclasses like nth-child for markup that I don't expect to change much during development.

Comment: @bfavaretto Thanks, I usually prefer using classes as well, it looks clearer when looking over the code and easier to work with later.